# How do I change the rate modules output to "# of users like this"?

Tags: 7, rating

I am using the [Rate](http://drupal.org/project/rate) module.

The current display for my thumbs up widget is:

```
(thumbs up image) 2 users have voted, including you.
```

I would like to change it to:

```
(thumbs up image) 2 users like this
```

How do I change the default tpl to accomplish this?

```
print $up_button;

if ($info) {
  print '<div class="rate-info">' . $info . '</div>';
}

if ($display_options['description']) {
  print '<div class="rate-description">' . $display_options['description'] . '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used the module. But looking at the [code](http://drupalcode.org/project/rate.git/blob_plain/32749463cf6dccf7aca5e76f8450e9dd2d378c42:/rate.module), you essentially need to override the preprocess function in the module which is used to generate the string.

Open `rate.module` in an editor and search for the text string that you are looking to change. In this case, this string would be something like "*have voted*", which should lead you to the function named `rate_preprocess_rate_template_thumbs_up()`. This is the function that you should look to *override*. You can see that the strings are added as part of two `format_plural` calls and should be straightforward to amend in the override function.

You can perform the override either from a custom module or from your theme's `template.php` file. Since the module is using a *preprocess* function to make its changes, I recommend using a *process* function (note the difference in name) when you override it. There should be plenty of [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/173880) and examples available on drupal.org and drupalSE to aid you if you are unfamiliar with overriding.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [String Overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module and add the following to the config:

original: @count users have voted, including you.

replacement: @count users like this.